# How to set default date in Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker based on current input value so it appears on first use

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am trying to integrate the [Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) v4.17.42 into a webpage. I have a text field that is pre-populated with a date prior to calling the datepicker.

The field is as follows;

```
<input value="19/02/1986" class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="patient[date_of_birth]" id="patient_date_of_birth">
```

and I call the datepicker like so;

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
useCurrent: false,
maxDate: new Date(),
minDate: now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() - 110)
```

});

When I click in the text field the datepicker appears, but it shows the current month rather than February 1986. If I click out of the field and then back in, the datepicker disappears then reappears set correctly to February 1986.

What do I have to do to so the correct month appears the first time the datepicker is opened?

Comment: Can you create a sample http://plnkr.co?

Comment: Actually, I've resolved this by using 4.17.37. This seems to be a bug.

Comment: Yes it is. In fact it has already been reported here. https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1831. I wish I'd found this 3 hours ago!

Answer (score 0):

You can force a refresh programatically after the initialize:

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker('setDate', new Date(1986, 02, 19));
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker('update');
```

You can also add a property to the object when initalizing:

```
 setDate: new Date(1986, 02, 19)
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a setDate property. There is a defaultDate property but setting this doesn't seem to change the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

To use default data just try this

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

In this script new Date() returns the current value  that will be assigned to setDate attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, this is a bug in the latest versions, tracked here: [github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1831](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1831)

However, I found a work around that might be helpful in the meantime (if you don't want to use version 4.17.37):

```
var selectedDate = moment($('#patient_date_of_birth').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');
$('#patient_date_of_birth').data('DateTimePicker').viewDate(selectedDate);
```

Do this after your datepicker initialization.

This is the syntax needed hard refresh the view for this particular datepicker. You access the picker via `data('DateTimePicker')`, and the `viewDate()` method updates the date displayed by the picker.